# Particle collisions in the plane

Tags: kinematics, collision-detection

A particle, moving at a speed of $v$ and an angle of $\theta$ (taking $0^\circ$ to be the positive $x$-axis) collides with a fixed slope with a gradient of $m$.  How are $v$ and $\theta$ affected?

Context: for a simple 2D physics engine.

Comment: You’ll need to provide more information such as whether or not the collision is elastic.

Comment: Apologies! I suppose it should be elastic, since I want it to come to a halt over time (think of a pool table on a slant), but as it's a for a game engine really anything that works is good!